All calls to WCF service in .NET 8 extremely slow compared to .NET framework 4.7
I am attempting to convert a class library from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 8 that connects to an instrument that you communicate with via WCF. All calls to the server are much slower (not just the first call).
My performance test takes around 3 seconds in .NET Framework 4.7 (most of which is constructing the client proxy) but it takes 35 seconds in the project converted to .NET 8. The server and client are running locally on the same machine.
This is the code for the performance test:
public void PerformanceTest()
{
      var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
      Console.WriteLine("Start: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

      using (var target = MakeGaiaNetworkInstrument())
      {
           Console.WriteLine("After constructor: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

           Assert.AreEqual(true, target.Lock(), "Lock failed");
           var testParamStringName = "Parameter Name";
           var testValueString = "Value";
           target.SetParameter(testParamStringName, testValueString);

           Console.WriteLine("Before loop: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

           for (var repetition = 0; repetition < 10; repetition++)
           {
               Assert.AreEqual(testValueString, target.GetParameter(testParamStringName));
           }

           Assert.AreEqual(true, target.Unlock());

           Console.WriteLine("After loop: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
       }
}

Target is the client proxy.
The output on .NET Framework 4.7 is:
Start: 0
After constructor: 3310
Before loop: 3321
After loop: 3347

The output on .NET 8 is:
Start: 0
After constructor: 8508
Before loop: 12609
After loop: 35268

Added measurement for each method in the new code:
Start: 0
After constructor: 6567
Gaia Lock took: 2045
Gaia SetParameter took: 2043
Before loop: 10659
Gaia GetParameter took: 2030
Gaia GetParameter took: 2024
Gaia GetParameter took: 2047
Gaia GetParameter took: 2025
Gaia GetParameter took: 2030
Gaia GetParameter took: 2043
Gaia GetParameter took: 2052
Gaia GetParameter took: 2063
Gaia GetParameter took: 2042
Gaia GetParameter took: 2047
Gaia Unlock took: 2043 
After loop: 33112

It seems like there is a 2 second overhead on each call to the server
This is the code that creates the client proxy:
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { MaxStringContentLength = 100000, },
                UseDefaultWebProxy = false,
                BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
            };
this.server = new GaiaServicePortTypeClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(this.ServerUri));

I have tried the suggestions from:
Upgrade Net Framework 4.7.1 to Net 6 makes WCF service consumption slower
https://justsimplycode.com/2019/11/02/disable-header-100-continue-in-net-core-wcf-client/
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5002
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5184
And changed the code to:
ClientBase<GaiaServicePortTypeClient>.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;            
GaiaServicePortTypeClient.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOn;
            
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
    ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { MaxStringContentLength = 100000, },
    UseDefaultWebProxy = false,
    BypassProxyOnLocal = true,
};
            
server = new GaiaServicePortTypeClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(ServerUri));
server.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new HttpMessageHandlerBehaviour());

None of the changes have made a difference. I have also tried with an empty BasicHttpBinding and with UseDefaultWebProxy = true - nothing makes a difference.
The proxy code was generated with: "svcutil /d:"$(ProjectDir)\service" %WSDLFILE% /language:C# /async /internal /namespace:*,Unisensor.Gaia.Webservices /noconfig"
Changed to:
dotnet-svcutil -d "$(ProjectDir)\service" %WSDLFILE% --outputFile GaiaService.cs --sync --internal --namespace "*,Unisensor.Gaia.Webservices"
I have inspected the XML sent to the service with Fiddler and it seems to be identical. The server is written in C++ and can't be changed. I am running a freshly installed Windows 11 without any corporate bloat software.

You could try profiling and find out what part exactly is being so slow.

I have tried profiling but almost all of the time is in "stack traces without user methods". The server method does nothing interesting it keeps the string in memory and returns it so I highly doubt that the performance issue is in our code

I didn't expect the performance problem in your code, but I was hoping you would see which methods in the framework would show up as hot paths.

Ah dottrace doesn't seem to want to show what time is being spent in the different parts of the frame work it just says 61.2 % "stack traces without user metods". 13 % HttpInterceptingMessageHander.<>n_0. 10 % HttpInterceptingMessageHander.SendAsync 8.2 % generatedProxy_1.GetParameter

First of all, .NET Framework 4.7 is actually very different from .NET 8. In .NET 8, some of the old .NET Framework features were reimplemented to better accommodate the needs of cross-platform and modernization. This can lead to performance differences. .NET 8 introduces new features and optimizations, but it can also introduce some performance overhead. The network protocols and transmissions in .NET 8 may differ from those in .NET Framework 4.7, resulting in slower communication speeds.

At the same time, some classes such as System.servicemodel do not work with .NET 8. Replaced these with corewcf in .net 8.

@QIYou The server is written in c++ is used by other clients still on framework 4.7 and cannot be changed. I believe corewcf is for writing the server side System.servicemodel and all other refererences have been upgraded to the .net 8 version

Look at SoapCore or any other active SOAP client library. .NET 8 is actually .NET Core 8, a completely different platform. When .NET Core was created SOAP was already a legacy technology and people had realized that WCF's attempt to combine multiple network technologies (SOAP, .NET Remoting, DCOM, pipes) into one API had failed. All the complexity and bloat are caused by the attempt to handle all those protocols. There's no real effort to migrate WCF outside CoreWCF

This seems to be a bug in WCF - I have submitted a bug report on github:
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5498
I found a workaround, the bug seems to be related to DNS - if you pass the server ip address instead of servername there is no performance penalty
